# How to check if certain group of files of similar format exist in PHP?

Tags: php

I was wonder is there any possible ways to check if group of files exit with the format as: `$filename=$anything_id."_".random.".jpg";` random can be any. I have lots of files like

`gb_23232.jpg, gb_23122.jpg, gb_23332.jpg, gb_23422.jpg, gb_23732.jpg, gb_23922.jpg` and so on.

I want to delete any files that starts with `gb_`

Comment: do you need to do it in php, or can you use the command line?

Answer (score 0):

you can use these code

```
$mask = 'gb_*.*';
array_map('unlink', glob($mask));
```

another code

```
foreach (glob("gb_*.*") as $filename) {
    unlink($filename);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load the names of all the files in a directory, then loop through looking for any strings of names that contain "gb_".

```
<?php
$handler = opendir("directory/subfolder");
while($file = readdir($handler)){
if(strpos($file, "gb_") !== false){
//deleting stuff goes here
}
}
?>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can following possible which is in PHP Documentation. Dump list and search in string it contains 'gb'. link - [ScanDir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try to smt like this:

```
foreach (glob("/path/gb_*") as $filename) {
    //unlink($filename);
}
```

Read more about glob here http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.glob.php